# How do I allow Alphabetical input as a number?

Tags: python

```
a = 3.50
print"Price of Sandwich: $",a,
print""
Jeff =(raw_input('Enter how many of this item:')or 0.0)
if(Jeff.isalpha()):
    Jeff == 0
a = (Jeff * a)
print'Total: $'+ str(a)
print''
```

I need the alphabetical input to become a 0 instead of the program just crashing.
Thanks

Comment: What you want is `Jeff = 0` not `Jeff == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way  :

```
a = 3.50
print "Price of Sandwich: $",a
print
Jeff = (raw_input('Enter how many of this item:') or 0.0)
if(Jeff.isalpha()):
    Jeff = 0.0
a = (float(Jeff) * a)
print 'Total: $'+ str(a)
print
```

Comment: You are a Legend

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this :

```
    a = 3.50
    print"Price of Sandwich: $",a,
    print
    Jeff =(raw_input('Enter how many of this item:'))
    if (Jeff.isalpha()):
        Jeff =0
    a = (int(Jeff) * a)
    print'Total: $'+ str(a)
    print
```

This will change `Jeff` to `0` if the input is a letter so the program won't crash. And because `Jeff` is a string as you used `raw_input` ,to multiply it with `a` you need to change it to a integer using`int()`. As mentioned you don't use `==`double equals here,you use double equals if you're checking for a answer not when you are giving a variable a value.

Comment: @GAVDADDY Hope this explained some stuff